# Mpdf\Mpdf LoggerAwareInterface incompatibility with Psr\Log in php 8.1.12

Tags: php, mpdf

I get the following error when trying to use mpdf:

```bash
Declaration of Mpdf\Mpdf::setLogger(Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) 
must be compatible with Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface::setLogger(Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger): void
```

The most information I can find on the topic is [this](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/1622) but I can't find how to fix it.

There is mention of using the branch `php8-support` but I tried this and it doesn't work either.

Has anyone found a work around on this?

I am on php `8.1.12` and using `"mpdf/mpdf": "v8.0.13"`

Comment: Please share more details. Which version of `psr/log` do you currently use? If you are facing a bug with mPDF, why not report it on their issue tracker?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update 2023/05/03: Update mPDF to version 8.1.6, where `psr/log` `3.x` is supported and this message should not be present.

---

Versions and branches of mPDF have nothing to do with this.

mPDF is not compatible with `psr/log` `3.x` because of support of older PHP versions (which do not have return type hints).

One or more of your dependencies, or yourself, are forcing `psr/log` library to version `3.x`. You can find out which by calling `composer why psr/log` in the console.

Downgrade the `psr/log` library to `2.x` - just enter/change `"psr/log": "^2.0"` line in your composer.json file and run `composer update`. This should resolve the issue.

If any of your libraries enforce `psr/log` `3.x` (do not allow lower major versions), the `composer update` call will fail and you will have to either downgrade or replace these libraries, or not use mPDF.

Comment: Thanks @Finwe. Is this in the docs? I looked for it but couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: I don't think this is a docs material. Composer should not allow you to install mPDF alongside psr/log 3.x in the first place... Can you try to reproduce this and create a Discussion about this in mpdf's github?

Comment: It's an issue that others have faced (for example [here](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/1622)) so the above answer in the [troubleshooting](https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/known-issues.html) section would be handy :)

I'll take another see if I can get it to fail with `psr/log` `3.x` and open an issue if I do.

Answer (score -1):

i had this problem and resolve with this command
my PHP version is 8.1 and use 10 version of Laravel

```
//because this packages use psr/log
composer remove niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf
composer remove mpdf/mpdf
composer remove psr/log
//install again
composer require psr/log=v2.*
composer require mpdf/mpdf
composer require niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf
```

Comment: What's the point in using such an old version of `mpdf/mpdf`? 8.0.17 is 18 months old, why not use a current version?

Comment: I have no clue what that link **should** point to, but currently it redirects me to a website that asks me to install a Chrome extension. Also, please add all clarification to your answer, not to the comment section

Comment: "the newer version of mpdf needs 8.2 version of PHP" - that's just wrong. Even the latest release of mPDF (v8.1.6, released in May 2023) has a minimal requirement of PHP 5.6

Answer (score -4):

Downgrade psr/log from 3.x is not a good idead and involve security risk. It may create conflict with other packages which require newer psr/log.
Mpdf v8.0.16 support psr 3.0, install it first.
Then go to vendor/psr/log/src/LoggerAwareInterface.php

Change from:

```
public function setLogger(LoggerInterface $logger):void;
```

Change to:

```
public function setLogger(LoggerInterface $logger);
```

This change will solve your issue.

Note:It is only minor change and not having big influence. If you keep on using psr/log v2, you can downgrade and all of your package must use psr/log v2 for consistence. If you want using psr/log v3, making change in vendor folder is the only choice because setlogger in mpdf is not compatible with setlogger in LoggerAwareInterface. It's common practice that change should not be made in vendor file and keep on using psr/log v2 is better choice.

Comment: Editing files in the `vendor` folder is never a good idea, and if there was any "security risk" with using `psr/log` v2, it would better be fixed in that version

Comment: It is only minor change and not having big influence. If you keep on using psr/log v2, you can downgrade and all of your package must use psr/log v2 for consistence. If you want using  psr/log v3, making change in vendor folder is the only choice because setlogger in mpdf is not compatible with setlogger in LoggerAwareInterface. I agree with you that change should not be made in vendor file, keep on using psr/log v2 is better.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it